# Trigger to update a counter when data is entered in another table's column

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table named Count and a table named Records.

Count table:-

```
| countRecords |    typeRecord      |
|--------------|--------------------|
|      0       |   type of record   |
```

Records table:-

```
|     ID     |     recordType   |
|------------|------------------|
|     id     | type of record   |
```

I want to update the countRecords as per the type in recordType in table Records. Whenever a user enters a recordType, I want to update the counter for it in Count table and whenever a user deletes a row/entry, I want to decrement the counter. How do I do this using a trigger?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need two triger

The insert trigger, as long as it only needs to update a row, can be done so.

If your database is more complex and you have fpor example an empty recordType   , you need more code

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_recods_insert
AFTERINSERT
ON recods FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE count_table SET countRecords  = countRecords  +1 WHERE typeRecord = NEW.recordType   ;
```

AN UPDATE Trigger ist somewhat more complex as you need to change teh count when the type changes

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_recods_UPDATE
AFTER UPDATE
ON recods FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (OLD.recordType <> NEW.recordType) THEN
    UPDATE count_table SET countRecords  = countRecords   -1 WHERE typeRecord = OLD.recordType   ;
    UPDATE count_table SET countRecords  = countRecords  +1 WHERE typeRecord = NEW.recordType   ;
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Serg is right, to complte the set

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_recods_delete
AFTER DELETE
ON recods FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE count_table SET countRecords  = countRecords  - 1 WHERE typeRecord = OLD.recordType   ;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However I have a question. What do you mean by "<>" ?

Comment: .. and Delete too. Next the name of your trigger is after_.. but trigger code is BEFORE  why?

Comment: @Nzed if you update a row in recods and you didn't change the record type it not necessary to change the count

Comment: @Serg i added a DELTER trigger and changed it to AFTER